# Will the .net mvc application work without any user defined route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Can anyone tell me if it is necessary to keep a route.config file?....or more precisely...will the application work without a predefined user route or even a default route?

Comment: With no routes registered at all, you won't be able to access any of your controllers and you'll get a whole bunch of 404 errors

Answer (score 1):

Routing is one of the primary aspects of the MVC framework which makes MVC what it is. While that is possibly over-simplifying, the routing framework is where the MVC philosophy of "convention over configuration" is readily apparent.

Routing also represents one of the more potentially confounding aspects of MVC. Once we move beyond the basics, as our applications become more complex, it generally becomes necessary to customize our routes beyond the simple flexible default MVC route.

[Read More](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC).